# C# How to get processor number of clocks per second?

Tags: c#

I need to get the processor number of clocks per second for a research project made in c#.

I read the documentation for Stopwatch.Frequency and Stopwatch.IsHighResolution but I really can't figure it out if this is really what I need.

I made a test with a compiled .EXE on 2 different machines and the results are different.

The code used for the test is:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Frequency
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", Stopwatch.Frequency, Stopwatch.IsHighResolution));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: `Stopwatch` is for measuring time.